# Why does my MySQL database not contain all the data sent to it from Scrapy?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, transactions, bulk-load

I am an SQL novice and am trying to store a load of data into a MySQL database using python. For some reason, after sending approx. 24,000 rows of data to my database I find that it only contains 1,300.

My hard drive is not full.

I did not get an error when pushing the data (for which I use python).

It might have something to do with the storage engine, InnoDB, but considering that those 1,300 rows occupy 176 KB I doubt it. It might be the last points because I was not able to understand the documentation as it talks more about the limits in terms of data size in bytes and pages rather than number of rows and I can't relate.

The statements I used when handling the database from python are as per below.

1. Database creation

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE database_name
   ```
2. Table creation

   ```
    "CREATE TABLE table_name ( \
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, \
    price INT, \
    model VARCHAR(40), \
    year INT, \
    body VARCHAR(30), \
    milage INT, \
    engine_size FLOAT, \
    engine_power INT, \
    transmission VARCHAR(10), \
    fuel_type VARCHAR(30), \
    owners INT, \
    ultra_low_emission_zone INT, \
    service_history VARCHAR(30), \
    first_year_road_tax INT, \
    full_manufacturer_warranty INT \
    );
   ```
3. Pushing data to the database

   ```
    "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES\
    ("+str(id_carrier.carried_id + counter)+",\
    "+price+", \
    '"+model+"', \
    "+year+", \
    '"+body+"', \
    "+milage+", \
    "+engine_size+", \
    "+engine_power+", \
    '"+transmission+"', \
    '"+fuel_type+"', \
    "+owners+", \
    "+ultra_low_emission_zone+", \
    '"+service_history+"', \
    "+first_year_road_tax_included+", \
    "+manufacturer_warranty+" \
    );"
   ```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: Adding code use to process my data. Entries to the database are made line by line.

```
counter = 0

# retrieving offers
offers = response.xpath('//li[@class = "search-page__result"]')[1:-2]
for offer in offers:
    # reinitializing the data which can be missing
    year = '0'
    body = 'unlisted'
    milage = '1000000'
    engine_size = '50'
    engine_power = '1000000'
    transmission = 'unlisted'
    fuel_type = 'unlisted'
    owners = '100'
    ultra_low_emission_zone = '0'
    service_history = 'unlisted'
    first_year_road_tax_included = '0'
    manufacturer_warranty = '0'
    # getting price of offer
    price = Selector(text=offer.extract()).xpath('//div[@class = "product-card-pricing__price"]//span/text()').get()
    # formatting price of offer
    price = price.replace(',','').replace('£','')
    # getting offer model
    model = Selector(text=offer.extract()).xpath('//h3[@class = "product-card-details__title"]/text()').get()
    # formatting model
    model = model.replace('\n','').replace('BMW ','').strip().lower()
    # going through some clustered data and applying formatting
    clustered_details = Selector(text=offer.extract()).xpath('//li[@class = "atc-type-picanto--medium"]/text()').getall()
    for detail in clustered_details:
        if 'reg' in detail.lower():
            year = detail.split(' ')[0]
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'convertible' or \
                detail.lower() == 'coupe' or \
                detail.lower() == 'estate' or \
                detail.lower() == 'hatchback' or \
                detail.lower() == 'mpv' or \
                detail.lower() == 'suv' or \
                detail.lower() == 'saloon':
            body = detail.lower()
            continue
        elif 'miles' in detail:
            milage = detail.lower().replace(',','').replace(' miles','')
            continue
        elif detail[0] in '0123456' and detail[1] =='.' and detail[2] in '0123456':
            engine_size = detail.lower().replace('l','')
            continue
        elif detail[0].isnumeric() == True and detail[1].isnumeric() == True and 'p' in detail.lower():
            engine_power = first_number(detail)
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'manual' or detail.lower() == 'automatic':
            transmission = detail.lower()
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'diesel' or \
                detail.lower() == 'diesel hybrid' or \
                detail.lower() == 'diesel plug-in hybrid' or \
                detail.lower() == 'electric' or \
                detail.lower() == 'petrol' or \
                detail.lower() == 'petrol hybrid' or \
                detail.lower() == 'petrol plug-in hybrid':
            fuel_type = detail.lower()
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'full service history':
            service_history = 'full service history'
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'part non dealer' or detail.lower() == 'part service history':
            service_history = 'part service history'
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'full dealership history' or detail.lower() == 'full dealer':
            service_history = 'full dealership history'
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'ulez':
            ultra_low_emission_zone = '1'
            continue
        elif 'owner' in detail.lower():
            owners = detail.lower().split(' ')[0]
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'first year road tax included':
            first_year_road_tax_included = '1'
            continue
        elif detail.lower() == 'full manufacturer warranty':
            manufacturer_warranty = '1'
            continue
        else:
            print('Unexpected value ',detail)
            exit()
    counter += 1
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO " +make+ " VALUES\
        ("+str(id_carrier.carried_id + counter)+", \
            "+price+", \
            '"+model+"', \
            "+year+", \
            '"+body+"', \
            "+milage+", \
            "+engine_size+", \
            "+engine_power+", \
            '"+transmission+"', \
            '"+fuel_type+"', \
            "+owners+", \
            "+ultra_low_emission_zone+", \
            '"+service_history+"', \
            "+first_year_road_tax_included+", \
            "+manufacturer_warranty+" \
        );"
    db.execute_query(insert_query, connection)
    # print(price,model,year,body,milage,engine_size,engine_power,transmission,fuel_type,owners,ultra_low_emission_zone,service_history,\
    #      first_year_road_tax_included,manufacturer_warranty)

id_carrier.carried_id = id_carrier.carried_id + counter
try:
    next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class = "pagination--right__active"]/@data-paginate')[0].root
except IndexError:
    print("All the pages have been scraped")
    exit()
url = ".."+next_page
time.sleep(3 + random.uniform(0,4))
yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers = header)
```

EDIT 2: Adding in database management code for functions not visible in code in EDIT 1

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd

def create_server_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password, db_name = None):
    connection = None
    if db_name != None:
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=host_name,
                user=user_name,
                passwd=user_password,
                database=db_name
            )
            print("Connection to database " + db_name + " established.")
        except Error as err:
            if err.errno != 1049:
                print(f"Error: '{err}'")
                exit()
            print("Requested database does not exist. Creating it.")
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=host_name,
                user=user_name,
                passwd=user_password
            )
            create_database_query = "CREATE DATABASE " + db_name
            create_database(create_database_query, connection)
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=host_name,
                user=user_name,
                passwd=user_password,
                database=db_name
            )
            print("Connection to database " + db_name + " established.")

    return connection

def create_database(query, connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        print("Database created successfully.")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

def execute_query(query, connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
    except Error as err:
        if err.errno != 1050:
            print(f"Error: '{err}'")
            exit()
        print("Table " + query.split('TABLE')[1][1:].split(' ')[0] + " exists. Continuing script.")
```

Comment: How do you _know_ that you sent 24000 rows? If your insert doesn't do any existence checking, then either your looping logic didn't send through all rows, or if you are using optimistic bulk insert and the failed rows are failing a unique or other constraint. Please show us the code that processes the file.

Comment: I have posted the python code that does the processing. You are right, I don't know for if the data is sent and stored as I believe it is. I will modify my code to build a .CSV file to verify that is the case. The data is inputted row by row.

Comment: Check the response from `db.execute_query(insert_query, connection)` I am not familiar with a library that has that method, but usually SQL execute methods return the number of rows that are affected. Look for number of rows being zero, or less than 1 (some implementations return -1 to indicate an error) then do further investigation on the input SQL and parameters. Otherwise have a look at the data that was inserted, was it always the first 1300? of is there some other pattern to the successful rows or the excluded ones.

Comment: Perhaps it is your paging method, 1300 is a suspiciously round number, how many records are in a page, how many pages is 1300 records... this might not have anything to do with SQL at all...

Comment: If everything else checks out, the answer from @o-jones sounds like it is the most likely culprit https://stackoverflow.com/a/67864509/1690217

Comment: You are right. The database submission function were written by me in a separate file. Adding that code as well to the post. Apologies for not adding in all the detail from the start. Because I am new to this I was expecting myself to be doing something stupid and for the cause to be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I guess (but I'm not sure) you're trying to do one gigundo INSERT operation with all 24k rows in its list of values.

MySql has a (long) limit on statement length. Usually it's no problem, but it may have truncated your vast INSERT.

Try doing it in chunks of 100 rows.

**Edit** :  Thanks for the clarification of your data flow.  MySQL's python connector does not [automatically commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html) INSERTs and UPDATEs.

This means the MySQL server accumulates your changes in a [transaction](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-transaction-management-using-commit-rollback/). 24K rows is many many rows for a transaction, and it's possible it exceeded the transaction buffering space.

So, after each 100 rows or so inserted you should [do this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html).

```
cnx.commit()
```

You can, alternatively, do `cnx.autocommit = True` when you set up your connection.  But bulk-loading by committing the rows one-by-one is very slow.

The python connector is different from most other language connectors in that it does not do autocommit by default. That's confusing.

Comment: I am adding the rows 1 by 1. My code is going through each offer on a page, and thorough the 2,400 pages, adding the data as if goes around. I will post part of the code.

Comment: I had not changed the `autocommit` parameter so I expect that is probably it. Apologies for not sharing enough detail from the beginning. Did not expect the problem to be buried so deep. I have amended and am re-running the data scraping again. Will come back with feedback in a few hours. Am also creating a CSV on the side this time. I have noted down your observation regarding slowness with submitting 1 by 1.  In this case I am scraping slow to try and my IP from getting banned so speed is not an issue but it is a good note for future projects. Thank you !

Comment: I have run the code part way through and discovered that both the database and CSV have stopped adding data after exactly 1000 entries. This points to something being wrong with my Python code as Chris was suggesting above. The autocommit would probably have become my next problem after I would had solved this one.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you Chris Schaller and O. Jones for helping me out. With their guidance I managed to debug the problem to the scrapy web crawler. It has a max number of 100 actions per response as detailed in the documentation [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-items) and in the StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354380/scrapy-stops-crawling-after-a-few-pages).